# Button Click in Jade without Script Tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I saw this code for button click for Jade

```
   button(onclick=foo)
    script(foo(){alert('foo');})
```

I don't want any script tag or any JavaScript code in my rendered page .How can How can I make any button click in Jade from express or node.js file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inline javascript :

```
button(onClick="javascript:alert('foo')")
```

However, this is not really optimal, and using a script tag/external script makes your code more readable and easier to debug.

You cannot however use a `onclick` event without using any JavaScript. If your constraints are 'no JS', you cannot have an alert on click (`alert` is also a javascript function)

If you wish to separate concerns as much as possible, you can have your JS code in a separate .js file, but will still need to include that file in your rendered page.

Edit : An explanation on server/client interactions :

When you create a server in Node/Express, you are generating assets (html pages) from your templates. This generation, as well as what do to when a user reaches a route within your site, are handled by the server.

The server "serves" the source code page (the doc you see by clicking 'view source' to the client, which then interprets it.

If the browser sees Javascript code, it knows how to read it and will add all the events, alerts, etc that you have placed in the code. it will then be able to process those interactions. Your button event in this case has nothing to do with Node/Express

**TL;DR : the server only sends source code to the client, who's in charge of reading it and interpreting it.**

Comment: xShire i dont want any onclick code on my renderer page

Comment: Is not it possible for node js ?

Comment: it's not possible for anything, if you want javascript functions in your browser, you need javascript code in the client

Comment: server side code will not handle your client side interactions, like clicking buttons, displaying alerts, etc

Comment: @HüseyinOkumuş i've tried to explain some more, see edit